# How to implement database mirroring using SQL on two geographically separate servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-mirroring

Good Day

I need to implement database mirroring on two geographically separate servers.

I have been tasked with ensuring that there should be a backup of the databases that is not more than 1 day behind the live databases.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrgZT.png) is a link of a sketch of what I currently have installed on the servers and how the servers are connected via a WAN.

My question is, given my current configuration. What do I need in order to make mirroring possible? Essentially, what do I need to purchase or upgrade in order to make mirroring possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs to the DBA site

Comment: Be prepared to answer questions about the SLA requirements, capacity, workload, DR plan and so on.

Comment: raise your question here as well: https://dba.stackexchange.com/